# Angular: Change String to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

Apologies if this is simple. I just couldn't figure-out how to do it. Searched on this site on how to dynamically change variables and evaluate them etc but can't figure out how to do what I want.

Problem: I have a variable that I set to a value:

```
vm.toggleDrop = function($switchToggle){
        vm.switchValue = "switch"+$switchToggle;
        //Here 

    };
```

Where it says "Here", I need to instantiate a new variable that is called whatever is the result if the above statement eg; switch1 then set it true or false as a boolean. eg: switch1 = false;
Therefore again, if $switchToggle parameter was "Test", I need to dynamically create a variable called switchTest and set it true or false.

Is such a thing possible ?
Thanks all

Comment: Already answered here I believe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?(I created vm variable just for code snippet, ignore it)

```js
var vm = {};

vm.toggleDrop = function($switchToggle){
        vm.switchValue = "switch"+$switchToggle;
        vm[vm.switchValue] = 'whatever';
        console.log(vm);
    };

vm.toggleDrop('true');
```

Also if you do not need to attach variable to vm object, best answer will be @nastyklad provided(using `window[vm.switchValue]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function setVariable(name){
    var variableName = 'switch' + name;
    vm[variableName] = true;
}
```